# using pipenv with gitlab ci

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, pipenv

I'm using `pipenv` in my local development and integrating Gitlab CI/CD to deploy and testing.

I do not want to generated `requirements.py` file every time I install a new package. Therefore I want to use `pipenv` with `Gitlab` runner too.

My `gitlab-ci.yml` file contains

```
stages:
  - test
  - deploy

test:
  stage: test
  script:
  - apt-get update -qy
  - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
  - apt-get install -y python-dev python-pip
  - pip install pipenv
  - pipenv install
  - pipenv run py.test src/


...
```

But pipeline is failing with error

```
$ pipenv install
Warning: the environment variable LANG is not set!
We recommend setting this in ~/.profile (or equivalent) for proper expected behavior.
Warning: Python 3.6 was not found on your system…
You can specify specific versions of Python with:
  $ pipenv --python path/to/python
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/_compat.py:86: ResourceWarning: Implicitly cleaning up <TemporaryDirectory '/tmp/pipenv-fmGiYD-requirements'>
  warnings.warn(warn_message, ResourceWarning)
```

I even tried with `--python 3.6` flag but same error.

My `Pipfile` contents are

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
django = "*"
...
pytest = "*"
pytest-django = "*"
pytest-cov = "*"
pdbpp = "*"
mixer = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.6"
```

> Update 2

replacing `python-dev python-pip` with `python3-dev python3-pip` is installing python version **3.5** and while running the command `pipenv install` giving following error

```
RuntimeError: Click will abort further execution because Python 3 was configured to use ASCII as encoding for the environment. Consult http://click.pocoo.org/python3/for mitigation steps.

This system supports the C.UTF-8 locale which is recommended.
You might be able to resolve your issue by exporting the
following environment variables:

export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
export LANG=C.UTF-8
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add environment variables to your gitlab-ci.yml file:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/#gitlab-ci-yml-defined-variables

Also use a python docker image instead of installing python:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#define-image-and-services-from-gitlab-ci-yml

```
image: python:3.6
test:
    stage: test
    variables:
        LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
        LANG=C.UTF-8
```

Comment: I replaced `python-dev python-pip` with `python3-dev python3-pip` but now it is giving error. I have updated question with error.

Comment: did you try adding the environment variables as the error message suggests?

Comment: also if you really need 3.6 'apt-get install python3.6'

Comment: Yes, I tried adding but not as variables instead added as a command. That error was gone but still `Warning: Python 3.6 was not found on your system…` error

Comment: apt install 3.6 explicitly

Comment: `apt-get install -y python3.6 python3-pip` giving **E: Unable to locate package python3.6**

Comment: I had tried both repositories of `jonathonf` and `deadsnakes` but both were giving `W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu cosmic Release' does not have a Release file.` error

Comment: seems like a pain point with pipenv. https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/1050 maybe 'pip freeze' isn't looking so bad anymore

Comment: I understand but here the issue is with installing `python 3.6` as well. Even if I do not use `Pipenv`, I do require `python 3.6` as this is the project requirement.

Comment: use a docker executor maybe with python 3.6 image instead of installing python https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#define-image-and-services-from-gitlab-ci-yml

Comment: yes, that worked. just added `image: python:latest` on top of `test` stage and removed all installation scripts. It's working as expected. One little suggestion is required. In my local system, I'm generating test coverage. Should I skip that coverage generation on gitlab test? If not, how would I see the generated coverage report?

Comment: If you want to save the coverage report you need to specify it as an artifact: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/pipelines/job_artifacts.html